# Postgres trigger based partitioning, insert NEW.* gives values (10,,,)

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I am doing Postgresql partitioning and I have such insert in the trigger:

```
EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || tablename || ' VALUES ' || NEW.*;
```

When I am inserting partial data (with default values)

```
INSERT INTO my_table(id, col) VALUES (1, 10);
```

to a table with a trigger I get an syntax error because the EXECUTE statement in the trigger builds such an insert sql statement (error by continued commas):

```
 INSERT INTO my_table_p3 VALUES (1,10,,,,)
```

How can I solve an error? 
P.S. I have ~300 columns in my table.

Answer (score 1):

The proper syntax for this construct on a reasonably recent version of PostgreSQL would be:

```
 EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || tablename || ' VALUES ($1.*)'
   USING NEW;
```